# reactiveValues and Global Variables in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

There seems to be some others who are confused by this same issue but after reading and attempting the solutions I found here, I am still stumped. Help!

I have a Shiny App that takes the difference between prices between two dates and returns a list of 4 tables one for each type of Product for each Date, and the same 4 tables for the Price Deltas of the two Dates. 
(DATE1, DATE2, DELTA)

On my output screens after Calc, the tables remain empty until the user clicks on the inputSelectors which prompt the table to refresh.

I am still struggling to understand how to get the table to automatically refresh when the Calculation ends.

Here is the logic in my Server.R file concerning the output of one of dataTables:

```
dataset_HL <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset_HL, 
           "Deltas" = DELTA$HL,
           "Date 1" = DATE1$HL, 
           "Date 2" = DATE2$HL)
})

termGroup_HL <- reactive({
    switch(input$termGroup_HL,
           "ALL" = rowIndex$ALL, 
           "BOM" = rowIndex$BOM,
           "QTR" = rowIndex$QTR,
           "CAL" = rowIndex$CAL)
})

values_HL <- reactive({
    data <- dataset_HL()
    colnames(data) <- locations$HL
    data <- cbind(Terms = rownames(data), data)
    rows <- termGroup_HL()
    return(data[rows, ])
    })

output$table_HL <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(values_HL(),
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                  pageLength = 25, 
                  lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100)
              ))
})
```

Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer finally and of course it was already answered by Joe Cheng here, [Shiny Reactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703711/shiny-reactivity).

Simply adding a call to my action button, input$GET_Dates, inside my reactive function triggered the re-calc of the table.

I also simplified my reactive values function.

```
values_HL <- reactive({
    input$GET_Dates
    dataset     <- switch(input$dataset_HL, 
                    "Deltas" = DELTA$HL,
                    "Date 1" = DATE1$HL, 
                    "Date 2" = DATE2$HL)

    termGroup   <- switch(input$termGroup_HL,
                    "ALL" = rowIndex$ALL, 
                    "BOM" = rowIndex$BOM,
                    "QTR" = rowIndex$QTR,
                    "CAL" = rowIndex$CAL)
    data <- dataset[termGroup, ]         
    data <- cbind(Terms = rownames(data), data)
    data 
})



output$table_HL <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(values_HL(), 
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                  pageLength = 25, 
                  lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100)
                  ))
})
```