# R shiny reactive return more than one object

Tags: r, shiny

I am making use of the example provided in in the answer to this question: [Shiny Reactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703711/shiny-reactivity)

They make use of two return statements in the reactive function. I believe return(x) is just a mistake. However, I am wondering if I can return more than one object with one reactive statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of `reactive()` as any regular function that returns a value, it just happens to return a reactive value and to always be called automatically when needed.  In a regular function, how do you return more than one object?  You can return a list, for example.  You can do the same with `reactive()`.